# Extent not found on NASA's Black Marble monthly images - How to set it?

Tags: raster, r, extents, terra, night-time-images

I downloaded NASA's Black Marble monthly nighttime light (NTL), [VNP46A3](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/missions-and-measurements/products/VNP46A3/). The product is in `.h5` format and it contains the radiance NTL raster as well as the scientific data sets (SDS) in order to remove bad quality pixels etc.

When I import the `.h5` raster I am getting this warning: `Warning message: [sds] unknown extent.`

Then I converted the `.h5` into a `SpatRaster` using the below code:

```
library(terra)
s <- sds(paste0(wd, "VNP46A3.A2018182.h06v05.001.2021125183820.h5"))

# extract single image as spatraster from h5
r <- s[5] # I extract the radiance raster

writeRaster(r, paste0(wd, "rad.tif"))
```

When I type `ext(r)`, I get:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 2400, 2400, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 2400, 0, 2400  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source      : r.tif 
name        : AllAngle_Composite_Snow_Free 
min value   :                            0 
max value   :                        65535
```

My question is how can I set the correct extent (and CRS) to the `r` raster in `R`?

I am using `R` 4.3.1 and RStudio `RStudio` 2023.06.2+561.

Comment: Have you got a link to the actual .h5 file you downloaded?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I downloaded the file using a downloaded icon right after I selected the study area. I'm checking your method as we speak.

Comment: I found it via the "Data Archive" link, following the structure of your file name, but it did require a NASA login (EarthData?) which I had and I think is mostly free.

Comment: Exactly. Generally speaking, in order to download the data, I followed the procedure found on NASA's youtube video called _NASA ARSET: Black Marble Background, Use, and Applications, Part 1/1_. In this video they explain step by step how you can download a tile(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the data using `terra::rast` - I'm not sure what `sds` wins you here, this works:

```
r <- rast("VNP46A3.A2018182.h06v05.001.2021125183820.h5")
```

Define the coordinates to be lat-long WGS84:

```
crs(r) = "epsg:4326"
```

Now the documentation says the data are 15 arc-minute cells. That means for these 2400x2400 grids they span:

```
> 2400*(15/(60*60))
[1] 10
```

exactly ten by ten degrees.

Which ten degrees? That's encoded in the file name. Set these up:

```
h = 6
v = 5
```

Then you can reset the extent by computing the appropriate offsets and adding ten degrees:

```
ext(r) = c(-180+h*10,-180+(h+1)*10, (8-v)*10,(8-v+1)*10)
```

And we can plot on a map background to confirm:

```
tm_shape(r[[1]]) + tm_raster()
```

[image]

Which looks good. There's some assumptions here, like the WGS84 coordinate system and the grid being aligned to WGS84 10 degree grids, but this seems to work. Its possible it should be shifted by half a cell size. Check it out on a few more files.

If you want to get the tile numbers from the data, they are stored as netcdf global attributes, which you can get from the file using the `ncdf4` package:

```
> library(ncdf4)
> n = nc_open("VNP46A3.A2018182.h06v05.001.2021125183820.h5")
> as.numeric(ncatt_get(n, 0)$VerticalTileNumber)
[1] 5
> as.numeric(ncatt_get(n, 0)$HorizontalTileNumber)
[1] 6
> nc_close(n) #tidyup
```

Now let's put this all in a function:

```
readA3 <- function(f){

    r = terra::rast(f)
    crs(r) = "epsg:4326"
    n = ncdf4::nc_open(f)
    v = as.numeric(ncdf4::ncatt_get(n, 0)$VerticalTileNumber)
    h = as.numeric(ncdf4::ncatt_get(n, 0)$HorizontalTileNumber)
    ncdf4::nc_close(n)

    ext(r) = c(-180+h*10,-180+(h+1)*10, (8-v)*10,(8-v+1)*10)
    r
    
}
```

Which we can use like this:

```
 h6v6 = readA3("./VNP46A3/2018/182/VNP46A3.A2018182.h06v06.001.2021125183917.h5")
 h7v6 = readA3("./VNP46A3/2018/182/VNP46A3.A2018182.h07v06.001.2021125183820.h5")
 h6v5 = readA3("./VNP46A3/2018/182/VNP46A3.A2018182.h06v05.001.2021125183820.h5")
```

using the bulk-downloaded files and folders from the "Data Archive". Plotting shows they are in the right place, but beware that `tmap` seems to do a bit of approximation (or possibly transform to web mercator) which can show gaps - saving as TIF and loading into QGIS shows two tiles meeting at a perfect corner which is telling me this is most likely spot on:

[image]

As noted elsewhere, its possible modern versions of GDAL can interpret the metadata and work this out for themselves, but my installation with GDAL 3.4.1 doesn't.

As a final test I downloaded all the images from one folder, looped over them, converted every one's first layer to a TIF, and loaded all 300 or so layers into QGIS.

[image]

Comment: I plotted the results by overlaying them with some other data I have in `QGIS` and it seems that they are overlaying perfect. But I will download few more tiles from around the globe to validate your method, as you said.

Comment: Yeah I didn't check if the horizontal tile is numbered from N-S or S-N. Also, two neighbouring tiles should not overlap at the edges of their pixels, so any of the usual "half pixel out" problems should show up in that case.

Comment: the v is numbered from N -> S while the h from W -> E. If there is a _half pixel out_ problem I will let you know.

Comment: Edited to fix the vertical error and wrap it all up into a function.

Comment: I will check it and if something's wrong I will post it here.

Comment: I just received a reply on a post I made in NASA's forum (https://forum.earthdata.nasa.gov/viewtopic.php?t=4637). I quote:

This is how you calculate the bounding box using the horizontal (h) and vertical(v) time number –

 

WestBoundCoord = (10*HorizontalTileNumber) - 180

NorthBoundCoord = 90-(10*VerticalTileNumber)

   

 EastBoundCoord = WestBoundCoord + 10

SouthBoundCoord = NorthBoundCoord - 10.

@Spacedman your code is working, I just wanted to mention what NASA replied.

Comment: Yes thanks I took a 50:50 chance with my original code and got it wrong!